# How can I get width and height of a video from an input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the width and height of a video from a input button. But my code doesn't work. I get the file but I want to get the info from the file variable.

```
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //Get file
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(){
        var height =reader.naturalHeight;
        var width =reader.naturalWidth;
     }
});
```

Comment: `FileReader` doesn't know about file formats, such as images and video so it has no concept of height or width. Have you tried searching for alternative JavaScript functionality or libraries that could do the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the FileReader to convert it from binary to base64 and then back to binary is a wast of resources and memory, use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead. And you don't have to append the video to the DOM

```js
fileButton.addEventListener('change', evt => {
  const file = evt.target.files[0]
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  video.onloadedmetadata = evt => {
    // Revoke when you don't need the url any more to release any reference
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
  }
  video.src = url
  video.load() // fetches metadata
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileButton">
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this.